# Как сделать рефакторинг кода?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ооп, веб-программирование

Есть код в котором меняются только имена класса и переменные с счётчиком . Но он трижды повторяет себя . Можно можно ли его сократить до одной красивой функции ?

код:

```
var itt = 0;
var itt_2 = 0;
var itt_3 = 0;

$('.first_div > img').each(function(i, elem) {
  itt++;
  console.log(itt);
  var lefted = -20 * itt;
  $('.first_div > img').eq(itt).css({
    'left': lefted + 'px'
  });
  //console.log(lefted)  
});

$('.sekond_div > img').each(function(i, elem) {
  itt_2++;
  console.log(itt_2);
  var lefted = -20 * itt_2;
  $('.sekond_div > img').eq(itt_2).css({
    'left': lefted + 'px'
  });
  //console.log(lefted)  
});



$('.sird_div > img').each(function(i, elem) {
itt_3++;
console.log(itt_3);
var lefted = -20 * itt_3;
$('.sird_div > img').eq(itt_3).css({
  'left': lefted + 'px'
});
//console.log(lefted)  
});

});
```

Comment: Эти счетчики используются еще где-то кроме приведенного куска кода?

Comment: @ Dmitriy Simushev, нет

Comment: @Dementiy1999, да можно

Comment: а что вообще должен делать этот код??? что-то мне подсказывает что тут вообще не нужны переменные, да и сама функция может упроститься

Comment: Grundy, есть 3 дива в которых картинки(которые сформировались динамически), код просто подвигает одну картинку на другую на 20 "px". А такой "мудреный" был потому в каждом блоке разное количество картинок

Comment: @Dementiy1999, посмотри update к моему ответу, похоже вот что действительно нужно было :-)

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо это действительно крутая магия )

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31640/discussion-between-grundy-and-dementiy1999).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Еще вариант без глобального массива

```
var fun = function(elClass) {
  var itt=0;
  $(elClass).each(function(i, elem) {
    itt++;
    console.log(itt);
    var lefted = -20 * itt;
    $(elClass).eq(itt).css({
      'left': lefted + 'px'
    });
    console.log(lefted)
  });
};

fun('.first_div > img');
fun('.sekond_div > img');
fun('.sird_div > img');
```

**UPDATE:**
после небольших раздумий, я пришел к выводу что это можно упростить до

```
function fun(i, elem) {
    var lefted = -20 * i;
    $(this).css({
        'left': lefted + 'px'
    });
    //console.log(lefted)  
}

$('.first_div > img').each(fun);
$('.sekond_div > img').each(fun);
$('.sird_div > img').each(fun);
```